# Reactive Extensions: How to ignore short state changes

Tags: system.reactive

I want to observe state change in Internet connection from my Xamarin App. I use the Connectivity Plugin which offers an ConnectivityChanged event which I convert into an Observable. This works fine.

The problem is when the Phones switches e.g. from 3G to 4G there is a short disconnection which I would like to ignore.

So far I tried with `Throttle` and `Distinct`until changed but with no luck as I always get a value even if the state is the same as before the disconnect.

So far I tried this:

`var connectionEvent = Observable.FromEventPattern<ConnectivityChangedEventHandler, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs>(
                    handler => handler.Invoke,
                    h => CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += h,
                    h => CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged -= h)
                        .Select(x => x.EventArgs.IsConnected)
                            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                                .DistinctUntilChanged()

                                    .StartWith(CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                                        .Publish();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather hard to figure out what's happening with "Stuff's firing when I don't want it to". Luckily, Rx has some robust testing support. Here's some test code ( using Nuget `Install-Package Microsoft.Reactive.Testing`). `source` represents noise coming from the Android API. `target` is your set of operators on top of it. `expectedResults` is the results:

```
TestScheduler ts = new TestScheduler();
var crossConnectivity_Current_IsConnected = true;
var source = ts.CreateHotObservable<bool>(
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(200.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(false)),
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(300.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(true)),
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(5550.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(false)),
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(5600.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(true)),
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(5800.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(false)),
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(7700.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(true)),
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(7800.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(false)),
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(13000.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(true))
);

var target = source
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), ts)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .StartWith(crossConnectivity_Current_IsConnected);

var expectedResults = ts.CreateHotObservable<bool>(
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(0.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(true)),
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(5300.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(true)),
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(12800.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(false)),
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(18000.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(true))
);
```

The only problem I'm seeing is the notification at 5300. You can get rid of that by re-ordering the operators a bit. Look at my `target2`:

```
var target2 = source
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), ts)
    .StartWith(crossConnectivity_Current_IsConnected)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    ;

var expectedResults2 = ts.CreateHotObservable<bool>(
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(0.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(true)),
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(12800.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(false)),
    new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(18000.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(true))
);
```

...and if you want to run the tests, here's the runner code.

```
var observer = ts.CreateObserver<bool>();
target.Subscribe(observer);
var observer2 = ts.CreateObserver<bool>();
target2.Subscribe(observer2);
ts.Start();

ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expectedResults.Messages, observer.Messages);
ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expectedResults2.Messages, observer2.Messages);
```

...and you'll need this class

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static long MsTicks(this int i)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i).Ticks;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, augment `source` to describe when/how it occurs.

Comment: Thanks, amazing, that I use a Select should not change it, right?

Comment: The reordering was the key. Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use the helper methods to reduce `new Recorded<Notification<bool>>(200.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext(false)),` down to `ReactiveTest.OnNext(200.MsTicks(), false),`. Further more, if your test class was to use `ReactiveTest` as a base class, then it is reduced further to `OnNext(200.MsTicks(), false),`. Using the same trick, and noticing that the your can use the `AssertEqual` ext method, your Assertions can be reduce to `observer2.Messages.AssertEqual(
  OnNext(0.MsTicks(), true),
  OnNext(12800.MsTicks(), false),
  OnNext(18000.MsTicks(), true));`